# How to create custome post type in wordpress RT Themes

Tags: wordpress

How to create Custome post type for property i want to add custome post type in wordpress. with some feature :

1. user can see all the listing
2. user can click on any listing and the related info of this listing shown on other page
3. how to integrate payment getaway for custome post type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   you can use type plugin for this . or
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/ 
   this plugin
```